# exec function does not work out

Tags: php, apache, exec

```
<?php
    exec("whoami");

?>
```

I can be more explicit with the code . Although When I'm trying to call the php file with my browser nothing happens (of course I'm using apache and the whole).

Note : The safe_mode is activated, I'm using php5, php interpreter seems to be nice when running other functions, I'm a ubuntu user.

Then what is wrong?

Comment: If the `safe_mode` was *enabled*, as you say, then `exec` would be disabled. Raise the error_level and look into the error.log to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `echo` function. Executing `whoami` using the `exec` function will run the program but show you nothing… you want to spit out the result too.

```
echo exec("whoami");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo the output of the `exec` command somewhere.

[PHP documentation for exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) contains the example with `whoami`, look at the `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Right in the docs for [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, turn off safe mode. Safes you lots of headaches.

Otherwise, is the php file owned by the same user that Apache runs as?
On Ubuntu, this will usually be www-data.

Try:
`sudo chown www-data /path/to/you/script.php`
Then run again.